# How to change the constraint's arity from n to 3?

Tags: constraint-satisfaction

How to change the constraint's arity from n to 3?
I know how to perform binarization of constraints, explained here: https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/b172/_media/courses/b4b36zui/binarization.pdf, but I don't know how to get a constraint of arity 3.

A ternary constraint is one based on four variables, for example, constraint $C=\{(X,Y,Z) \& X+Y=Z\}$.

And the binary constraint is simply based on two variables: $A=\{(X,Y) \& X<Y\}$.

When given a constraint of arity n, so a constraint based on n variables I want to make a ternary constraint out of it.

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean to change a constraint's arity from $n$ to 3? Since binary constraints can also be seen as ternary constraints (which ignore one of their inputs), why would that not suffice for you?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, "Since binary constraints can also be seen as ternary constraints (which ignore one of their inputs)" - I didn't think of that. Could you explain this?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what binary and ternary constraints mean to you. Expand the question so that it doesn't assume that the reader is an expert in the particular terminology used in your class. Give examples, briefly explain binarization, and explain what you don't know how to do. At present, you are just not supplying enough details for us to be certain what it is that you're actually asking.

Comment: Sure, sorry for that.

Comment: What kind of constraints are you interested in? Are they all of the form $(x_1, \dots, x_n, y) \wedge \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le y$?

Comment: @Steven basically I'm interested in all kinds of constraints.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think that the answer depends on the kind of constraints...

Comment: My original comment still stands. Any binary constraint is trivially a ternary constraint. For example, the binary constraint $x=y$ on the variables $x,y$ is the same as the ternary constraint $x=y$ on the variables $x,y,z$ (for any variable $z$).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thanks a lot.